# Template is not displayed for the route parameter Angularjs 1.4.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angular-router

when i try to route using route parameter, partial templates does not get loaded(and no error is displayed).But if i hard code the url in config file, it works. i am using angular 1.4.7 version.

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
   <ul>
     <li><a ng-href="#/algorithms/{{1}}">Category A</a></li> 
     <li><a ng-href="#/home">Home</a></li>                                                  
     <li><a ng-href="#/algorithms/2">Category B</a></li>
     <li><a ng-href="#/algorithms">Category C</a></li>
     <li><a ng-href="#/algorithms/test">Category Test</a></li>
     <li><a ng-href="#/testCase/someDynamicValue">dynamic link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider){

   $routeProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $routeProvider.when('', {
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
   $routeProvider 
  .when('/home',{
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/home.html?',
    controller : 'homeController'
  })
 .when('/algorithms', {
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/algorithms.html?',
    controller : 'algoController'
   })

   // *this does not work*

  .when('/algorithms/:algoId', {
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/algorithmsDetails.html?',
    controller : 'algorithmDetailsController'
   })

   // **below works**

  .when('/algorithms/test', {
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/algorithmsDetails.html?',
    controller : 'algorithmDetailsController'
   })
   // *this does not work*
   .when('/testCase/:dynamicId', {
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/testCaseDetails.html?',
    controller : 'testCaseDetailsController'
   })
 });
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you're using a version of AngularJS that was released 2 years ago?

Comment: no specific reason @Baruch.

Comment: Why do you have `?` on each templateUrl? Also use angular-ui-router

Comment: @AluanHaddad this is how i received from person who was working on on it. if i remove  ? then also it does work.

Comment: "?" is the issue. try this example. http://jsfiddle.net/harshakj89/1Lra0ofr/

Comment: Hi @Harshakj89 it is still not working. my whole project is in [github](https://github.com/vtarun/Burnwal). Please check where i am making mistake.Thanks